# Rigid Body Major Problem

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

**Here is a link to a video of my problem - https://youtu.be/5J7ZVIfxcw0.**

**Link to my blender file - https://www.mediafire.com/file/qrr0kldf0xeamzq/1.blend/file.**

Yo, I want to animate this bouncy platform that I have made using rigid body constraints with the type being Generic Spring. When the create falls onto the create a want to leave blenders simulator to animate it because later on I'll be changing the weight of the cube and I don't want to manually animate every different weight animation. However, I do want to animate the platform (the bouncy thing) along the Y-axis.

**I've tried** lots of different ways including; Just animating the platform but that means I have to check the animated box in the Rigid Body settings and that leaves it locked on the Z-axis which is not what I want.

**The second** way I tried is to animate the empty (Constraint) and the anchor listed in my "Scene Collection" but this method simply did not work and the platform did not follow the animated anchor and constraint.

**The third** way I've tried is putting two verts on each side of the platform and making them Rigid Body passive objects to push the platform but this just ended up glitching out the platform. This is what I expected to be honest.

**The Forth** way I tried to do this is using checking the "Animated box" and giving the Platform some speed then keyframe unchecking the box before the box hits the platform, This method worked well up to the end where the platform started to slow down to a stop and even if I check the box again before it got to the end it would look strange and bad. Here is a link to a video including the problem - https://youtu.be/tEMQapEaj74.

**The Fifth** way I tried is using force fields to push the rigid body along but this cropped up too many more problems.

**The final** method I can remember trying is parenting the platform to a different object and animating that but it results a lot like the first method I tried.

At this point I'm willing to try anything including addon that people know of and the such, If anyone knows of a work around or a better way to do it or just to tell me I've been doing it wrong, I greatly welcome your comments.

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: can u please add a link to an animation how the end result should look like? i still have no idea what you want to achieve...

Comment: i am not sure whether you understood the rigid body system. You can only animate OR (!) use physics. Yes, you can change this per frame. Since i have no idea what you want, i did this: i just put a motor constraint to a box, constrained it to y and moved your spring with that: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8PEC.gif but as i wrote...it is totally unclear to me what you want to achieve. You should elaborate that and improve your question to make that crystal clear.

Comment: So sorry chris did not realise what you meant. Here is a "blocked out animation" of a sort of result I want, you can see where I want the floating platforms to be with the wobble, **https://youtube.com/shorts/Lr8nSqlY1O0?feature=share**.